# wp8 binding when click button

Tags: binding, windows-phone-8

I just want to make binding with my list box when i click the button.
This is my code in file .cs

```
      private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
        if(user_data.Text!=null)
        {
            user_info = user_data.Text.Trim();
           words= user_info.Split(' ');

           foreach (string word in words)
           {
               letters = word.ToCharArray();

               for (int i = 0; i < letters.Length; i++)
               {
                  string s = letters[i] + ".jpg";

                   souce_data.Add(new input_data(s));                       
               }
               phoronic_name.DataContext = souce_data;
           }
        }
      }
```

---

and this is my list box

```
  <ListBox x:Name="phoronic_name" SelectionChanged="phoronic_name_SelectionChanged" Foreground="Orange" >
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>                    
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>    

                </ItemsPanelTemplate>  
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>                    
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >                     

                       <TextBlock Padding="3,0,3,0"
                  Text="{Binding letters}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}"/>
                       <Image Source="{Binding souce_data}" Height="80" Width="80"/>

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>   
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>               
        </ListBox>
```

---

But when I click the button, there is no data

Answer (score 0):

So '`souce_data`' is the collection you want to bind.
Put it as [ItemSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) of `Listbox` instead of DataContext

```
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       //your code

       phoronic_name.ItemSource=souce_data;
    }
```

Comment: do u mean should i change from DataContext to ItemSource i do it but still there is no result

Comment: yea , i mean it. Please give a background for your data template stackpanel & check again.And also make sure that your collection has built properly.